# Mapping Json string to map or hashmap field in java

Tags: java, json, dictionary, jackson

Say I have the following JSON string returned from server:

```
{
    "response":{
        "imageInstances":{
            "one":{
                "id":"1",
                "url":"ONE"
            },         
            "two":{
                "id":"2",
                "url":"TWO"
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

in codehaus Jackson `@JsonProperty`, how can I get a `HashMap` object out of it?

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAnySetter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MSShow {
  @JsonProperty("imageInstances") private HashMap<String, Temp> images;//// HOW DO YOU CONVERT IT TO HASH MAP??????
  @JsonAnySetter public void ignoredField(String key, Object value) { }

  private class Temp {
    @JsonProperty("id") private String id;
    @JsonProperty("url") private String url;
    @JsonAnySetter public void ignoredField(String key, Object value) { }
    }
}
```

At the end of the day, I want the hash map generated based on the returned JSON string to be
(written in java pseudo)

should return me a Temp object with fields `id=1` and `url=ONE` if I call

```
images.get("one")
```

should return me a Temp object with fields `id=2` and `url=TWO` if I call

```
images.get("two")
```

Comment: Haven't done any serious delving or testing, but, for one, I'd say Jackson might have a problem with your nested class `Temp` being a) private, and b) an inner class (non-static, hence bound to the instance of the containing `MediaSlideShow`). So I'd start with making `Temp` `public static`.

Comment: And do you specifically need a `HashMap`? If not, consider a `Map<String, Temp>` instead and let Jackson worry about what implementation to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work as is, with one small modification: you are using extra "response" entry. So typically you would either use a wrapper POJO like:

```
class Wrapper {
  public MSShow response;
}
```

to map structure properly. Or you can use `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` Feature (from `DeserializationConfig`) to do this automatically, although name of the class needs to match if so.

Result will indeed be a `HashMap` if the field type is that (which it is). If it wasn't you could also use:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=HashMap.class)
```

to force specific subtype to be used.