# json parsing with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, nested

I am using the [Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for conversion of a JSON string to Java objects

My json is:

```
{  
   "human":{  
      "fname":"anjali",
      "lname":"malhotra"
   }
}
```

I want this to be converted into a Java class with following structure:

```
public class Human
{
  String fname;
  String lname;
}
```

I can successfully convert it into

```
public class HumanWrapper
{
  Human human;
}
```

But, I wanted to know if there is a way I can directly convert it into the Human format. I read about custom deserialization but was reluctant for that approach.

Comment: You can use `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` feature. Examples you can find here: [JSON Jackson deserialization multiple keys into same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064917/json-jackson-deserialization-multiple-keys-into-same-field), [Jackson - deserialize inner list of objects to list of one higher level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54424576/jackson-deserialize-inner-list-of-objects-to-list-of-one-higher-level), [Mapping Json string to map or hashmap field in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286785/mapping-json-string-to-map-or-hashmap-field-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by configuring ObjectMapper to use [`DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE) :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

and annotatating your `Human` class with [`@JsonRootName`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.html) annotation :

```
@JsonRootName("human")
public class Human {
....
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I will try this out and update the result.

Comment: Related question:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950529/parse-json-string-using-jaxson-root-value-customization

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `HumanWrapper` class as your human object is defined inside you json object

```
{
    "human": {
    }
}
```

If you able to change you API to send just a `human` object like this

```
{  
  "fname":"anjali",
  "lname":"malhotra"
}
```

Then you woudn't be bothering to have a `HumanWrapper`

Comment: In the current framework in my Organization, changing the API response is not possible.

And I felt that adding a wrapper just for this is maybe not the best approach