# Parse json string using jaxson root value customization

Tags: java, json, jackson, nested

I have a huge JSON string as a response to a rest call.
Part of the response has the following structure.
I am using com.fasterxml.jackson

```
“historicalData”: {
     “1585573790000”: {“score”:23.54, “count”:3},
     “1585487390000”: {“score”:12.65, “count”:2}
    },
//1585573790000 -> being the epoch time
```

The model I thought of so far is ArrayList of

```
private class HistoricalData {
        Long epochTime;
        Double score;
        Longcount;

    }
```

But I am unable to map the epoch time.

Answer (score 1):

your class `HistoricalData` does not match the JSON structure.
You could use a `Map` to match the JSON.

```java
Map<Long, HistoryData> historicalData;
```

Then the class `HistoryData` would look like this:

```java
class HistoryData {
    private Double score;
    private Long count;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Then you could process the map like:

```java
historicalData.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
    // do something with the entry
    // entry.getKey() would return the epochTime
    // entry.getValue() would return the HistoryData object
});
```

**But to be honest** it would be better if you could change the JSON structure to:

```
"historicalData": [
  { "epochTime": "1585573790000", “score”:23.54, “count”:3},
  { "epochTime": "1585487390000", “score”:12.65, “count”:2}
]
```

Then you could use a `List` of the class `HistoricalData`:

```java
private List<HistoricalData> historicalData;
```

And the class would look like:

```java
public class HistoricalData {
    private Long epochTime;
    private Double score;
    private Long count;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Comment: I could not agree more on the point for the JSON structure to be changed to 



"historicalData": [
  { "epochTime": "1585573790000", “score”:23.54, “count”:3},
  { "epochTime": "1585487390000", “score”:12.65, “count”:2}
]



I have made the request, wanted to know my options otherwise too.
Thanks  a lot let me try this out.